# Call function in NSThread

Tags: ios, swift

I have two threads which are constantly doing a lot of operations in the background. Both of them are constantly running a run loop.

At some point, one of the thread has to notify the other to perform a task in using that thread. I wanted to use performSelector, but it is deprecated now. How can I enqueue a task to the other thread?

Comment: Use NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Really? You found `performSelector:` but not `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`? Upgrade your Google-fu my friend.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I am using Swift, and these kind of methods are not available (they are deprecated, as I have said in the question).